# html - in order of elements - not by the order of writnig

Tags: html

In the following [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/FjYQH/51/) why do I see the "BBBB" before the "AAAA"? I expected the order to be according the `<tr>`.

```
<table style="text-align:left;">
  <tr>
    <td class="field">
      <label for="...">...</label> <br/>
      <myattributes>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <li>
              ...<a href="AAAA" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">AAAA</a>
            </li>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </myattributes>
      <label>
        <input data-autocomplete-source="..." />
        <a href="/dog">BBBB</a>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

​

Comment: That's not valid HTML. (And still isn't after your edit.)

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. Your HTML is completely malformed. You can't have `<label>` tags inside `<tables>` but outside `<td>`s, and you can't have `<li>` elements outside of `<ul>`/`<ol>`, and you definitely can't invent tags like `<myattributes>`.

Comment: 1. thought that in html 5 i can name any name to the xml element. 2. the label is insde div . but with other elements. isn't it possible?

Comment: @perry No, you can never use an arbitrary tag name. HTML is not XML. You also can't have a `<td>` as a parent of a `<tr>`. Please always ensure your code passes the [W3C's HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) without errors.

Comment: You may invent your own tags, that's perfectly valid in HTML5 and XHTML. The invented tags can be accessed in CSS and by `getElementsByTagName`. See an example http://jsfiddle.net/QLHFj/

Comment: alright. so what was wrong with myAttribute label?

Comment: (In addition to my comment: Being valid shall not imply that you should use it.)

Comment: I am new to html and seperating the areas of my html with meaningful elements tag names sounds like a good idea to me. What am I missing?

Comment: It's not valid per the specification, AFAIK. But that doesn't mean it will be rejected by the browser just because it's not valid, but what the browser will do varies. Further, in older IE versions tags it doesn't know about aren't styleable without Javascript.

Comment: HTML is meant to be read by the browser, not by a human reader. You should use comments `<!-- ... -->` before/after sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is messed up.

The nested `<tr>` closes the previous table row and add a new one.

By ending the row with `</tr>` you are currently not in a table line anymore.

When elements o the markup put between table rows, they are moved above the table in the DOM. That's way you see the "BBBB" first.

Comment: Can you please explain. I want one table with two rows and two <td>'s in each . I have written here only one row and one td because even this behaves unexpectedly. thanks

Comment: Updated. Is my answer better understandable now?

Comment: ao I put all my elements under one big td and still I see the same problem http://jsfiddle.net/PZS6P/9/

Comment: @perry You didn't read my answer! You have a `<tr>` inside a `<tr>`. The second one closes the open one. So the `</tr>` closes the row and you are not inside a `<tr>` anymore. The content between rows is put above the table.

Comment: So if I want this to be ordered correct I must create a new <table>. In brief - is there a shorter way to write this? Cause now it works but it is way too long http://jsfiddle.net/PZS6P/12/

Comment: Correct. :-) Way do you think thats too long? There are better ways to do your layout, not employing tables. But that's for another question.

Comment: thanks. Please suggest me a better way than tables for further reading.